# Changes to storyboard removing all ambiguous="YES" properties

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a complicated storyboard that has ~20 controllers developed over several years which has been working great. However, with most recent versions of Xcode, each time I make any changes at all to anything in the Storyboard, Xcode goes through and removes ambiguous="YES" in all my controllers. **Is there any way to stop Xcode from doing this?**

It fully breaks my layouts. Yes, I'd love to go rewrite every controller to not have this issue, but in practical terms these layouts are battle-tested on every device and OS version and that isn't a high value rewrite for me.

[image: Xcode removing ambiguous property]

Comment: I have this problem as well, it comes and goes randomly without me doing any actual changes to the storyboard.

Comment: In fact, it seems like Xcode is always reversing the state whenever it saves the storyboard. If it currently includes the string, it will not be present after saving. It it's absent, it will be added.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear you are running into issues with this.  Could you provide more information about the storyboard or a view controller sample that is running into layout issues after the change in `ambiguous=YES` status?

Generally, ambiguity is caused when there are not enough constraints to specify a size or position. For something like an Image View, if an image is specified, then it will have an intrinsic size, and it will be enough to specify just positioning constraints. If `ambiguous=YES` is disappearing on a re-save, then could there be enough constraints to specify its position and determine its size?  Deleting a positional constrain for the given view would put it back into “ambiguous”.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be too late to answer, but I run into the same issue and I wanted to let a guide to somebody else seeing the same issue in the future.

When a view frame position is ambiguous, the storyboard shows up a warning. Then some subviews include this `ambiguous="YES"` property in the storyboard file.

That means the view configurations for this **Trait** is not right. That doesn't mean that layout will not show properly when running the app since we might have Constraints that modify that frame positioning.

I don't know if this is showing up also for constraints ambiguity.